# Elastic Beanstalk - Rails Deploy using Github Gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've read a couple of other threads on SO discussing using `:git` in a GemFile but those solutions don't seem to be working for me.

Here's my .ebextensions/ruby.config file:

```
option_settings:
  - option_name: BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS
    value: "1"
  - option_name: BUNDLE_PATH
    value: "vendor/bundle"

packages:
  yum:
    git: []

container_commands:
  01bundle:
    command: bundle --deployment
```

Here's the one place I'm using Github in my GemFile:

```
gem 'themes_for_rails', :git => 'https://github.com/digitalmoksha/themes_for_rails.git'
```

And finally, the error I get in production.log that is related to this gem not being here:

```
I, [2013-08-28T13:29:26.979524 #26738]  INFO -- : Start adding themes to assets [true]
I, [2013-08-28T13:30:36.528844 #26808]  INFO -- : Start adding themes to assets [true]
I, [2013-08-28T13:32:47.069202 #26901]  INFO -- : Start adding themes to assets [true]
I, [2013-08-28T13:32:48.254604 #26913]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 123.456.789.10 at 2013-08-28 13:32:48 +0000
I, [2013-08-28T13:32:48.299025 #26913]  INFO -- : Processing by StaticController#index as HTML
I, [2013-08-28T13:32:48.323622 #26913]  INFO -- :   Rendered static/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.7ms)
I, [2013-08-28T13:32:48.331925 #26913]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 32ms
F, [2013-08-28T13:32:48.334631 #26913] FATAL -- : 
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `base_theme_stylesheet_path' for #<StaticController:0x00000003e16a10>):
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>Boundless</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag     "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    6:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag     current_theme_stylesheet_path('application'), media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    7:   <%= javascript_include_tag  "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    8:   <%= javascript_include_tag  current_theme_javascript_path('application'), "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    9:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2276887207485791953_34113280'
```

However, I can clearly see that the gems are packed in /var/log/eb-tools.log

```
Using themes_for_rails (0.5.2) from https://github.com/digitalmoksha/themes_for_rails.git (at master) 
Using turbolinks (1.3.0) 
Using uglifier (2.2.0) 
Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
```

Here's my full log file snapshot: https://gist.github.com/holtkampw/255d7bb00407fc615c76

Any ideas on what I can do to get this working correctly?  Perhaps my .ebextenions file is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This gist](https://github.com/gkop/elastic-beanstalk-ruby/blob/master/.ebextensions/ruby.config) will make it behave as you would expect from most rails environments.  I started using this in our deployments when I ran into the same problem with a gem sourced from a git repo.

From my understanding (at least as I recall), the rationale is that a git location is an untrusted source and could compromise or make your deployment unstable/not reproducible as instances are added/recycled.  While I agree, I still want the option to use them when I want.

Comment: This was a very helpful starting point.  With a few container_commands, I was able to solve my problems.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with active admin. You can put the gem into your vendor folder. Worked for me.

Put this in your gem file:

```
gem 'themes_for_rails', path: 'vendor/themes_for_rails', require: 'themes_for_rails'
```

You need to maintain this code into your /.ebextensions/ruby.config file:

```
option_settings:
  - option_name: BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS
  value: "1"
  - option_name: BUNDLE_PATH
  value: "vendor/bundle"
```

Don't forget to extract the git content of the gem into **vendor/themes_for_rails** folder.