# Configuring Ruby App on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having some issues getting the Shopify Dashing ruby app setup on Elastic Beanstalk. We run it successfully on Heroku but want to move it over to AWS where the rest of our applications live.

The issue:
I can get it to run and load up the basic app but none of the data loads and the console log throws connection errors). This is likely because the /events route doesn't return any data (although it does return a 200)

Things I've tried so far:

1. bundle --deployment and pushing up the vendors/bundle folder
2. variations of commands in .ebextension/ruby.config based on the answer (gist) in this question:  [Elastic Beanstalk - Rails Deploy using Github Gems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494219/elastic-beanstalk-rails-deploy-using-github-gems)

I'm thinking its a problem with the json gem since its the one thing I had to fiddle with to get it working on EB (added it to the gemfile:)

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'dashing'
gem 'json'
```

This code works locally and on Heroku and I'm using the Sample Dashboard generated with 'dashing start' so it's nothing custom that I've done.

Thoughts/Ideas? The app is currently running at (loads the basic HTML but has no values and you will see the errors in the console.log):
http://ch-dash.elasticbeanstalk.com/

Comment: I see that Heroku runs "bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment".

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [elastic-beanstalk](https://github.com/alienfast/elastic-beanstalk) gem for packaging and deployment. Noted the .ebextensions generated from `real-world example` section, or the sample file included.  It includes commands from [@gkop](https://github.com/gkop/elastic-beanstalk-ruby/blob/master/.ebextensions/ruby.config) that make it work more as expected in the eb environment.